# Kanwei minheap slow ruby

Tags: ruby, heap, containers, min

I had an implementation of a min heap in ruby that I wanted to test against more professional code but I cannot get Kanwei's MinHeap to work properly.
This:

```
mh = Containers::MinHeap.new # Min_Binary_Heap.new
for i in 0..99999
    mh.push(rand(9572943))
end

t = Time.now
for i in 0..99999
    mh.pop
end
t = Time.now - t
print "#{t}s"
```

The version I have performs the same popping operations on 100,000 values in ~2.2s, which I thought was extremely slow, but this won't even finish running. Is that expected or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would recommend anybody needing a max or min heap uses this instead: https://github.com/florian/rb_heap instead. It's documented well, is very lightweight and fast.

Comment: Indeed, the following problem fails when using Kanwei MaxHeap; with Florian's implementation then it works:
https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/may-leetcoding-challenge-2021/599/week-2-may-8th-may-14th/3737/discuss/1199502/Ruby-Custom-MaxHeap

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you are doing something wrong.

Looking at the source (https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms/blob/master/lib/containers/heap.rb), put a puts statement for when you finish setting up the heap. It looks like a very memory intensive operation to put the elements in (potentially resorting each time), so it might help you working through it.

I'm also not sure about him creating a node class for each actual node. Since they won't get cleaned up, there's going to be around 100,000 objects in memory by the time you are done.

Not sure how much help that is, maybe see how the source differs from your attempt?

Comment: Yeah I agree. It's a pretty awful implelmentation. I recommend the following wish is much faster that other libraries out there and has a really nice interface and documentation: https://github.com/florian/rb_heap